Two answers to the differential equation $x\mathrm dx + y\mathrm dy = x\mathrm dy - y\mathrm dx$
I have the following differential equation:

$x\mathrm dx + y\mathrm dy = x\mathrm dy - y\mathrm dx$


Method-1:
Notice that $x\mathrm dx + y\mathrm dy = \frac{\mathrm d(x^2 + y^2)}{2}$, so we substitute it for the LHS.
After which multiplying and dividing the RHS by $x^2$, the equation becomes: $$\frac{\mathrm d(x^2 + y^2)}{2} = x^2\mathrm d\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$
we get the differential of $\mathrm d\left(\frac{y}x\right)$ in the RHS, so we substitute it there.
Now, dividing both sides of above equation by $x^2 + y^2$, we can make both sides easily integrable and we get: $$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(x^2 + y^2\right) = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) + C$$
or, $\boxed{\ln\left(x^2 + y^2\right) = 2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) + C}$

Method-2:
Rewriting the given equation as: $$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \frac{x + y}{x - y}$$
Now, dividing the numerator and the denominator of the RHS by $x$: $$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \frac{1 + \frac{y}{x}}{1 - \frac{y}{x}}$$
Taking $\frac{y}{x}$ as $t$ and integrating: $$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x} = \int\frac{\mathrm dt}{f(t)-t}$$ where $f(t) = \frac{1+t}{1-t}$
We get: $\ln|x| = \ln\left|\frac{y}{x}\right| - 2\ln\left|1 + \frac{y}{x}\right| + \ln c$ ; $c>0$ is the constant of integration, is written inside $\ln$ for further simplifications.
Finally: $\boxed{2x^2 + 2xy - cxy = 0}$ is the answer.

The above two answers don't seem to be equivalent at all.
Where am I wrong?
Any help is appreciated!

Are they really different or are they equivalent? Check that

The first method seemes incorrect: $(1/2)d(x^2+y^2)=xdx+ydy$, which isnt the RHS in our equation, which is instead $xdy-ydx$

@PCeltide it is the LHS in our equation.

Ah, I see, sorry

@jimjim How can I check that, substituting values and checking if $c$ has the same value? Or do I simplify either to the other? The latter I don't know how to do.

@ApoorvaShukla The two values are non-equivalent. However I cannot spot the error as of now.

Can you outline the steps you've taken on substituting $y/x=t$? In particular, $dt=d(y/x)$ so there may be more to it?

I guess first one has to check the validity of the answer before checking two different looking answers are equivalent or not. There is an indefinite integral that can give two different looking trigonometric results, but after differentiating both we get the same result that checks that both are correct

A parameterized solution: $x=C e^t \cos t,\ y=C e^t\sin t.$

In polar coordinates, $\log r = \theta + C$, so $r = C' e^\theta$, a logarithmic spiral of pitch angle $\arctan 1 = \frac\pi4$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral

The second method also gives the same answer:
$$\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}=\frac{\mathrm dt}{\frac{1+t}{1-t}-t}$$
$$\implies\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}=\frac{1-t}{1+t^2}\mathrm dt$$
$$\implies\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}=\int\frac{\mathrm dt}{1+t^2}-\frac12\int\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\mathrm dt$$
$$\implies\ln|x|=\tan^{-1}t-\frac12\ln(1+t^2)+C$$
$$\implies\ln|x|=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)-\frac12\ln(x^2+y^2)+\ln|x|+C$$
$$\therefore\frac12\ln(x^2+y^2)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+C$$

In polar coordinate $(r, \theta)$ your equation is $dr^2\over 2$$=r^2d\theta$, so that $ d\ln r^2 = 2 d\theta$, or $\ln r= \theta +cte$

The solution to $d\ln r^2=2d\theta$ is not $r=\theta+\text{cte}$.

Right, thank you @Gonçalo!  $\ln r= \theta + cte$ ! thank you. This is thelogarithmic spiral, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral
